# How to load npm modules with Karma?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, mocha.js, karma-runner

I have some unit tests that use npm modules:

```
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import * as createLogger from "redux-logger";
import * as $ from "jquery";
import bootstrap from "../src/index";
import { getRoutes, getReducers } from "./stubs";

let expect = chai.expect;

describe("Some fixture...", () => {

    it("Some unit test....", () => {

        // ...
```

My application uses commonjs modules so I'm using the [`karma-commonjs`](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-commonjs) plugin to load my commonjs modules.

My problem is that `karma` is not able to find the npm modules:

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7 0.0.0) ERROR
  Error: Could not find module 'redux-thunk'
```

When the npm modules are globals like jquery I can add the following in the `karma.conf.js`:

```
files : [
    { pattern: "node_modules/jquery/jquery.js", included: true },
    // ...
],
```

How can I get Karma to understand where to find my npm modules when they are not globals?

Comment: You have to use a module packer that reads your JS and creates a concatenated file for you because most JS engines don't support modules yet.

Comment: I know how to do that but then the test coverage is not correct. Do you know how to overcome that issue?

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this?

Comment: No :( I ended up creating a bundle using browserify and loading it with karma instead of loading the npm modules directly

Comment: Thanks. I'm using webpack for the app, so could probably go that route for the tests, but I was thinking a bundle would kill coverage reports, which is the only reason I went from just jasmine to karma on top :(

Comment: I run the test on node using commonjs and create the test coverage them. After that I create a bundle and test in browsers with karma but I ignore the coverage results.